# Extract Pattern Matches / Remove Everything From Line Except Pattern

Tags: csv, awk, sed, grep

I'm currently using grep to try to extract specific text from each line of a file. It's successfully extracting the matches, however, I would like it to retain any lines that don't have matches (leave them as a blank line).

This is what I've tried so far (to get the name of the city on each line):

```
grep -o -P '(?<="city":").*?(?=")' input.txt
```

Example input:

```
email":"addictedtotlick7@gmail.com","last_name":"THOMPSON","first_name":"ERIN",,"__v":0,,,,"state":"NY","city":"north tonawanda"}
first_name":"chris","last_name":"caul",,"email":"dawgzn@mail.com",,,,"__v":0}
email":"lesliebo993@hotmail.com",,"first_name":"LESLIE","last_name":"RAMBO",,"city":"DOTHAN","state":"AL",,,"__v":0,
email":"malala@yahoo.com",,,"state":"GA","city":"NORCROSS",,"last_name":"KEO","first_name":"CATHY",,"__v":0,
email":"kdela@gmail.com",,"state":"FL","city":"HOLLYWOOD",,"last_name":"DE LA CRUZ","first_name":"KIDA",,"__v":0,
```

Desired output:

```
north tonawanda

DOTHAN
NORCROSS
HOLLYWOOD
```

Happy to try something in SED too if it's easier, but would prefer to avoid AWK as I have to work with big files, not sure I have enough RAM.

Comment: `grep` seems to discard empty matches.

Comment: Do you have a GNU awk? Try `gawk '{print index($0, "\"city\":\"") == 0 ? "" : gensub(/.*\"city\":\"([^\"]*).*/, "\\1", $0);}' file > newfile`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - this seems to produce the correct output when I run it, but I get this in the console for every line:

gawk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=db1.txt FNR=100000) warning: gensub: third argument `email":"uccelds@cox.net",,"__v":0,,,"state":"CT","city":"Rocky Hill","last_name":"Uccello","first_name":"Sebastiano"}' treated as 1

Comment: Ok, got it. Posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do that with GNU `awk`:

```
gawk '{print index($0, "\"city\":\"") == 0 ? "" : gensub(/.*\"city\":\"([^\"]*).*/, "\\1", 1);}' file > newfile
```

This means: if the line has `"city":"` in it (`index($0, "\"city\":\"") == 0`) then (`?`) print a blank line (`""`) or (`:`) print the result of the `gensub(/.*\"city\":\"([^\"]*).*/, "\\1", 1)` regex replacement:

- `.*` - any 0+ chars
- `\"city\":\"` - a `"city":"` substring
- `([^\"]*)` - Capturing group 1 (`\1`): any 0+ chars other than `"`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars.

The result of this is the value of Group 1. We need `gensub` and hence GNU awk as we need access to the capturing group value.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Perl

```
$ perl -nle ' if(/"city":"(.*?)"/) { print $1 } else { print "" } ' input.txt
north tonawanda

DOTHAN
NORCROSS
HOLLYWOOD

$
```

Answer (score 0):

Sed:

```
sed 's/.*city":"\([^"]*\).*/|\1/; /^[^|]/s/.*//; s/^|//'
```

Comment: And, talking about big files, sed is also much faster.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest another awk script

```
awk 'match($0,/(?<=\"city\":\").*?(?=\")/,m){$0=m[0]}1' input.txt
```

No problem with RAM and awk.

This script process each line.
If current line match RegExp `(?<="city":").*?(?=")`, then overwrite current line with match. Print current line.